# how to get dhtmlx table object with the table ID?

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

On a page if there are a dozen dhtmlx grids, is it possible to get the grid object using the table ID?

I need it to associate a table with its PDF/Excel generating buttons.  One way is to store the objects in an array.  IS there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are initializing dhtmlxgrid from the table, you can use name attribute of the table

```
<table name="mygrid1">
...
<input onlclick='mygrid1.toPDF(some)'>
```